How to emulate a DOS environment with a 640x240 display in QEMU using FreeDOS?
I am trying to create a DOS environment using FreeDOS and QEMU that emulates a device with a display height half 640x240 resolution that of a standard 640x480 resolution. I attempted the following command in QEMU:
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu 486 -drive file=freedos.img,format=raw -device VGA,edid=on,xres=640,yres=240

However, this did not achieve the desired effect of halving the display height.
I have tried several command options in QEMU, including:
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu 486 -drive file=freedos.img,format=raw -display sdl,gl=on,width=640,height=240

and
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu 486 -drive file=freedos.img,format=raw -display sdl -vga none -device virtio-vga,xres=640,yres=240

However, these also did not produce the expected results.
Does anyone know how I can successfully configure QEMU to achieve a 640x240 effective display area, or any method to emulate a display with these specific dimensions under FreeDOS? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What does Qemu show instead? Since FreeDOS runs in text mode: How many lines in what font do you expect?

Why do you call "qemu-system-x86_64" if you set the CPU to 80486? Don't you have "qemu-system-i386" installed, too?
